# Covering of a polytope by balls with midpoints at the vertices

Tags: linear-algebra, polygons, convex-hulls

I have a polytope $P=\operatorname{conv}(v_1,\ldots,v_m)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a ball $B_r(x)$ (with center $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and  radius $r>0$), such that $P\subset B_r(x)$. Is the statement
$$ P\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^mB_r(v_i)$$
true? Intuitively, I think it is true, but it is hard for me to prove it. For every point $w\in P$ I can show $d(w,v_i)\leq 2r$, since $d(w,v_i)\leq d(w,x)+d(x,v_i)\leq 2r$. But this only implies   $$ P\subset B_{2r}(v_i)\quad\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}.$$

Maybe it's better to formulate it without balls. I have $m$ points $v_1,\ldots, v_m$ and i know a point $x$ and a real number $r>0$ with $d(x,v_i)\leq r$ for all $v_i$. I claim for every $w\in\operatorname{conv}\{v_1,\ldots, v_m\}$ there is an $i$ with $d(w, v_i)\leq r$.

Comment: I do not know if this may be useful, but i think it suffices to prove theorem for convex polytopes (if the polytope is not convex, consider its convex hull).

Comment: Thank you :) Yes, it suffices to show the theorem for simplexes, because polytopes can be triangulated along their vertices.

Comment: If you can prove that the polytope is a compact set, consider the point that maximize the distance to the closest vertex (Weierstrass theorem guarantees the existence of a maximum) and the ball of radius $r$ center at that point. Then this ball contains all the vertices. For any other point, consider the ball of radius $r$ center at its closest vertex

Comment: Thank you :) But i know already the ball, which contains my polytope. I would like to translate it to all vertices. Maybe to formulate it without balls. I have $m$ points $v_1,\ldots, v_m$ and i know a point $x$ and a real number $r>0$ with $d(x,v_i)\leq r$ for all $v_i$. I claim for all $y\in\operatorname{conv}\{v_1,\ldots, v_m\}$ there is an $i$ with $d(y,v_i)\leq r$.

Comment: Yeah, i know you already know the ball, i'm just consider a new ball with the same radius but changing its center. Then the ball radius has to be bigger than that distance.

Comment: Hi :) I am very sorry, but can you explain it again. I don't want to have a bigger ball, i want to have more balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v\in conv(v_1\dots v_m)$, i.e., $v = \sum_i \lambda_i v_i$ with $\lambda_i\ge0$ and $\sum_i\lambda_i=1$.
Using Euclidean distance, we get
$$
\|v-v_i\|^2 = \|v-x+x-v_i\|^2 = \|v-x\|^2 + 2(v-x)^T(x-v_i) + \|x-v_i\|^2.
$$
multiplying with $\lambda_i$ and summation with respect to $i$ gives
$$\begin{split}
\sum_i \lambda_i \|v-v_i\|^2
& = \|v-x\|^2 + \sum_i \lambda_i2(v-x)^T(x-v_i) + \sum_i\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^2 \\
& = \|v-x\|^2 -2 \|v-x\|^2 + \sum_i\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^2 \\
& = - \|v-x\|^2  + \sum_i\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^2 ,
\end{split}$$
which is
$$
\|v-x\|^2  + \sum_i \lambda_i \|v-v_i\|^2 = \sum_i\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^2 .
$$
Now the right-hand side is less  than $r^2$ by assumption. This implies that at least one summand $\|v-v_i\|^2$ is less than $r^2$, which is the claim.
(Note that it does not matter whether all balls are assumed to be open or all are assumed to be closed). I am curious how to prove such a result (or whether it is true at all) for other norms on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am curious about a result for other norms as well :)

Comment: Yes. I was surprised that this was going to be such an easy calculation for the Euclidean norm, I checked my calculations several times.

Comment: For the 1-norm the claim is false. Theo Bendit has a counterexample https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208227/let-k-be-an-o-symmetric-body-that-covers-x-does-it-imply-operatorname/4208280#4208280