# Let $K$ be an $o$-symmetric body, that covers $X$. Does it imply $\operatorname{conv}(X)\subset X+K$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, discrete-mathematics, convex-geometry, polytopes

The question is inspired by the answer (and a comment) of daw at [Covering of a polytope by balls with midpoints at the vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203164/covering-of-a-polytope-by-balls-with-midpoints-at-the-vertices)

Let $K\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an $o$-symmetric ($K=-K$) convex body. Does $X\subset K$ imply $\operatorname{conv}(X)\subset X+K$? We already know, that it's true, if $K$ is an euclidean ball or ellipsoid.

Comment: Please revise the title of your question as it is math-only. Titles like this are discouraged for technical reasons - see [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: Ok, thank you, i'm sorry. I've edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Take $K$ to be the unit $1$-ball in $\Bbb{R}^3$:
$$K = \{(x, y, z) : |x| + |y| + |z| \le 1\},$$
and
$$X = \{e_1, e_2, e_3\} = \{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\},$$
respectively. Note that $x \in X + K$ if and only if $\|x - e_i\|_1 \le 1$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$.

If we consider the point $x = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$, then we see that $\|x - e_i\| = \frac{4}{3} > 1$ for all $i$, so $x \in \operatorname{conv} X \setminus  (X + K)$, proving the conjecture false.

Comment: Thank you :) So, the claim is false in general :(

Comment: @Jochen Yep. But, if you're interested in making this a trilogy, you could consider the least $\lambda_n \ge 0$ such that $X \subseteq K \implies \operatorname{conv} X \subseteq X + \lambda_n K$ for all symmetric bodies $K$ and $X \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ ($n$ is fixed). I suspect it will be helpful to remember Caratheodory's theorem: any element of $\operatorname{conv} X$ is a convex combination of at most $n + 1$ elements.

Comment: Using the same idea, one can find counterexamples for $p<2$ close to $2$: Take $K$ be the unit $1$-ball in $\mathbb R^n$, $x=(1,\dots 1)/n$, and let $n\to\infty$.