# Covering of a polytope by $p$-balls with $p\geq 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, polytopes, discrete-geometry

This is my last question in this area.

Let $p\geq 2$ and $X=\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$. Further let $x\in\mathbb R^n, r>0$ such that $\|x-v_i\|_p\leq r$ for all $i\in \{1,\ldots,m\}$.

Is it true, that for all $y\in\operatorname{conv} X$ there is a point $v_i\in X$ with $\|y-v_i\|_p\leq r$?

I know, it's true for $p=2$ ([Covering of a polytope by balls with midpoints at the vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203164/covering-of-a-polytope-by-balls-with-midpoints-at-the-vertices)) and it's false for $p=1$ ([Let $K$ be an $o$-symmetric body, that covers $X$. Does it imply $\operatorname{conv}(X)\subset X+K$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208227/let-k-be-an-o-symmetric-body-that-covers-x-does-it-imply-operatorname))

I tried to prove it myself for $p=4$, but it's nasty, because we have no Hilbert-space. Here is, what i've done so far:

If the assumpptions from above hold, let $y=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i$.
$$
\begin{align*}
\| y-v_i\|^4 &=\|y-x\|^4 + 4\sum_{j=1}^n(y_j-x_j)^3(x_j-v_{i,j})+ 6\sum_{j=1}^n(y_j-x_j)^2(x_j-v_{i,j})^2\\
&\quad + 4\sum_{j=1}^n(y_j-x_j)^3(x_j-v_{i,j}) + \|x-v_i\|^4
\end{align*}
$$
Multiplying by $\lambda_i$ and summing up yields
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i\| y-v_i\|^4 &=\|y-x\|^4 + 4\sum_{j=1}^n(y_j-x_j)^3(x_j-\sum_{i=1}^mv_{i,j})+ 6\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(y_j-x_j)^2(x_j-v_{i,j})^2\\
&\quad + 4\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(y_j-x_j)(x_j-v_{i,j})^3 + \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^4\\
&=\|y-x\|^4 + 4\sum_{j=1}^n(y_j-x_j)^3(x_j-y_j)+ 6\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(y_j-x_j)^2(x_j-v_{i,j})^2\\
&\quad + 4\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(y_j-x_j)(x_j-v_{i,j})^3 + \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^4\\
&=\|y-x\|^4 - 4\sum_{j=1}^n(y_j-x_j)^3(y_j-x_j)+ 6\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(y_j-x_j)^2(x_j-v_{i,j})^2\\
&\quad + 4\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(y_j-x_j)(x_j-v_{i,j})^3 + \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^4\\
&=\|y-x\|^4 - 4\|y-x\|+ 6\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(y_j-x_j)^2(x_j-v_{i,j})^2\\
&\quad + 4\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(y_j-x_j)(x_j-v_{i,j})^3 + \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^4
\end{align*}
$$
Hence, we get
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i\| y-v_i\|^4 +3\|y-x\|^4 &=  6\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(x_j-y_j)^2(x_j-v_{i,j})^2- 4\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(x_j-y_j)(x_j-v_{i,j})^3\\
&\quad  + \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^4\\
&=  \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(x_j-y_j)(x_j-v_{i,j})^2(2v_{i,j}+x_j-3y_j)  + \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i\|x-v_i\|^4.
\end{align*}
$$
It is left to show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_i(x_j-y_j)(x_j-v_{i,j})^2(2v_{i,j}+x_j-3y_j)\leq 3\|y-x\|^4.$$

Maybe there is an easier way by the monotonicity of the $p$-norms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wlog we can assume $x=0$.

Here is a counterexample to $p=\infty$: Take $n=3$,
$$
X = \left\{ \pmatrix{1\\1\\1}, \ \pmatrix{ 1\\-1\\-1}, \ \pmatrix{ -1 \\ 1\\-1}\right\} = \{ v_1 \dots v_3\},
$$
$$
y =\frac13(v_1+v_2+v_3) = \pmatrix{1/3\\1/3\\-1/3}.
$$
Then $X$ is contained in the $\infty$-unit ball, but $\|y-v_i\|_\infty=\frac43$.

Actually, this selection of vectors gives a counterexample for a large range of $p$'s.
Computing $p$-norms, we get
$\|v_i\|_p^p = 3$ and $\|y-v_i\|_p^p = \frac{2\cdot 2^p+4^p}{3^p}$. According to wolframalpha, $\frac{2\cdot 2^p+4^p}{3^p} > 3$ for $p>3.08...$.
Hence, the claim is false for this range of $p$.

I would suspect that taking $n\to\infty$ in the following pattern would produce counterexamples for all $p>2$:
$v_1$ vector of all ones, $v_i$ for $i=2\dots n$: entries $n$ and $i-1$ set to $-1$, all others to $+1$. $y=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nv_i$.